# Learning to Make a Sandbox

Tags: python, sandbox

I am learning about sandbox,and I would like to make one sandbox,
All I know about the sandbox is it is a platform to run untrusted codes with giving restricted access to resources to that code in order to protect our system from getting harmed due to that untrusted code,

i tried searching google but i did not get a satisfactory answers,
so what i would like know from all of you is where to start learning for sandbox,
my language of preference to code the sandbox will be python.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers provide a good sandbox that allows users to run code in mostly javascript. If you really want to use python then you can look for a [javascript python interpreter](http://www.skulpt.org/).

If you want to give users complete access to a computers resources while keeping them in a sandbox then you will need to look into [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization).